# How to pick random photo from folder

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

Lets assume that I have a folder.
The folder contains photos.
I want to pick a random one and, lets say, use different effects on them with pillow, the PIL fork.
How to?

Comment: In what programming language?

Comment: What have you tried specifically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps something like:

1. Get a list of the images in the folder.
2. Get the count of images in
   that list.
3. Generate a random number that falls in the range of your
   image count.
4. Load the image from the list that matches your random
   number.

Since you didn't specify a specific language or runtime environment, I've just generalized a possible way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```py
import random, glob

picture_files = glob.glob(picture_folder + '*.jpg')
random_picture = random.choice( picture_files)
# do something with random_picture
```